# JavaScript ES6 Modules: Avoid Polluting Global Namespace

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-5

### Background

When importing modules in JavaScript, we pollute the global namespace with the imported module's name:

**foo.js**

```
export foo() {..};
export const bar = 3.14;
```

**index.js**

```
import { foo, bar } from './foo.js';
```

---

### Question

In `index.js`, `foo` and `bar` live in the global namespace, right? So, let's say I publish this module and someone uses it in their HTML file, together with another script which also defines the variables `foo` and `bar` in the global namespace. Would we not have a collision then?

I guess this can be solved by wrapping everything within `main.js` in an IIFE. But, for some reason, ESLint complains about that, making me wonder if IIFEs isn't the preferred / recommended approach to protect the global namespace.

1. Will the global namespace be polluted with `foo` and `bar`?
2. If so, how should I avoid it?

Thank you.

Comment: Usually you'd export `{ foo: ..., bar: ... }`, then import the entire module using its name. That way you only have the module's name in the global namespace of `index.js`, and accessing `foo` can be done using `myModule.foo`.

Comment: Are you using any kind of bundler? If so, they treat each file as an IIFE, and thus, `foo` and `bar` will not be put on the global scope. If you are not, however, yes, what Chris G said is correct

Comment: Hi @ChrisG. I would still be polluting the global namaspace with `myModule` unfortunately. Also, it would force me to write in object/property syntax.

Comment: Per your example, "*In index.js, foo and bar live in the global namespace, right*?" Yes.

Comment: @ChrisG Just as an addon to my above comment: If I did not care about polluting the global namespace with `myModule`, I would rather do: `import * as myModule from '.foo.js'`. That way I am not forced to write the whole `foo.js` module in object/property syntax.

Comment: ESLint doesn't seem to complain when I tried wrapping everything in an IIFE.

Comment: @mhodges Hmmm, I did not know that. Do you have a link to webpack spec stating that they do that, by any chance? Somtimes I just use Gulp and babel, thus no bundler. But, for bigger apps, I use webpack.

Comment: Using https://eslint.org/demo, with ES6 selected, I used `(function(){
let foo = 5;
const bar = 3.14;
if(foo) foo += bar;
})()` and got "Lint-free!"

Comment: @TravisJ Try ESLint with the AirBnB config. Actually, I just noticed, I got a new ESLint error message on the IIFE / import: `Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`

Comment: @TravisJ That IIFE is no problem. It is when importing the module in `main.js` the problem with the namespace occurs. Importing objects/functions/primitives will pollute the global namespace with one or more variables, depending on how you do it.

Comment: One more thing to add: It is bad practice to export an entire object literal with multiple values, unless you are absolutely sure you/others need all of it always. Otherwise, you don't give importers an option to choose, and thus break tree-shaking, among other issues...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When importing modules in JavaScript, we pollute the global namespace with the imported module's name

No. Every module has its own module scope, in which all the imported bindings and top-level declarations live.

In a plain ES6 environment with only ES6 modules, you almost never use the global scope - all module code is strict mode code so you really have to make an effort to create a variable on the global object.

Module bundlers typically alleviate that by allowing you to declare a few exports to become global variables in the bundled script, so that you can easily access them in your page when using other scripts as well.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Just to be 100% certain that I understood you correctly: When I import a module (ES6 style), it is ONLY accessible in the `.js` file it is imported into. The imported module's name will not collide with identical names in other scripts?

Comment: Yes, the imports are created in a local scope. Unlike scripts, every module has its own implicit scope.

Comment: The only thing that can collide between modules are the module names (usually file paths) themselves. The exports are tied to the individual module.

Comment: Got it. It was just a bit counter intuitive to me, because I do access `foo` and `bar` in `index.js`, just as if they were global variables. Note: `index.js` is not a module itself, it is the top-level script directly linked in `index.html`. I guess we can think of `index.js` as being encapsulated in an IIFE, even though it is not?

Comment: They are bindings that refer to the variables in the `foo.js` module - and they're available only because you imported them. No, `index.js` is a module as well, only modules can use `import` syntax. You probably won't be able to create a `var global` in it. Your bundler/transpiler will of course put everything in a script wrapped by an IIFE, yes.

Comment: As a follow-up here, I tried to create a module with require.js module loader (AMD module system), and it shows that the top-level modules are not encapsuled. They live in the global scope. See the following codePen: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/wjZLPg